# Replacing while with foreach?

Tags: php

This line I am replacing:

```
reset($currencies->currencies); 
while (list($key, $value, $title) = each($currencies->currencies)) {
```

I think this is correct? or am I wrong?

```
foreach($currencies->currencies as $key => $value, $title) {
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it?

Answer (score 0):

The foreach construct has two forms: (foreach $foo as $bar), and (foreach $array as $key=>value).  Therefore, a comma-separated "value" isn't going to work, or so it seems, because you apparently have a multi-dimensional data structure (more than one $value for each $key).

You also don't say whether ($currencies->currencies) is an array, or another object.

If $currencies->currencies is an *object*:

```
foreach ($currencies->currencies as $myObject) {

    echo "The key is: "   . $myObject->key; 
    echo "The value is: " . $myObject->value;
    echo "The title is: " . $myObject->title;
}
```

If $currencies->currencies is an *array*:

```
foreach ($currencies->currencies as $myArray) {

    echo "The key is: "   . $myArray['key']; 
    echo "The value is: " . $myArray['value'];
    echo "The title is: " . $myArrat['title'];
}
```

Comment: It's an array, so it would be just foreach($currencies->currencies as $key => $value) {

Comment: @Tom Try it out first.

Comment: If the array has a key, a value, AND a title, it's fairly certain you're going to have to do it as I did with the "myArray", although you obviously can use your own name.  It all depends on the data structure. Post a "print_r" or var_dump() and you might get a better clarification.